# From a for loop, how do I store different length vectors into a single matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vector

I'm new to Matlab and programming in general. I'm trying to write a for loop where I'm able to keep the generated uneven length vectors into a matrix.

Here is my basic for loop:

```
G1 = [1 2 3 4];
for G1 = G1(1:end)
y = randn(1,G1)
end
```

I like to keep all values of y in the successive rows of a matrix like this:

[image]

I tried initializing y to a zero matrix first and running the for loop:

```
G1 = [1 2 3 4];
for G1 = G1(1:end)
y = zeros(4,4)
y(G1,:) = randn(1,G1)
end
```

The error is "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." I have also tried other variations of the for loop, all with initializing the zero matrix first but I received the same error message. How can I go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short answer to your problem is:

```
y = tril(randn(4));
```

This will return the [`lower triangular`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tril.html) part of a square matrix of size 4 of [`normally distributed random numbers`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html).

Note I hard coded the 4, but you could easily replace it with `max(G1)` or `length(G1)`.

As for your **first** code block, you should notice:

1. You are overwriting the variable `G1` when you define your for loop as such. Use another variable as the counter, such as `counter` for instance;
2. The variable `y` is overwritten each loop. You seem to have noticed it when you tried to fix in your second attempt. But you haven't taken into account that `randn(1,G1)` will give you different length vecors each iteration, which will cause dimension mismatch errors if you do not pay attention.

For your **second** code snippet:

1. `y = zeros(4,4)` is initialized inside the loop. It means any data you assign to it afterwards is wiped out each loop. You need to initilize your vector *before* the for loop;
2. Same observations for the first snippet also apply.

Finally, you should have a complete code as the following after the corrections:

```
G1=1:4;
y=zeros(4);
for counter=1:4
y(counter,1:counter)=randn(1,counter);
end
>> y
y =

  -0.43911   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.09520  -0.21825   0.00000   0.00000
   0.32569   1.04944  -1.19666   0.00000
   0.25531   0.68336  -1.02413   0.72696
```

Notice the indexing in `y(counter,1:counter)=randn(1,counter);` to avoid the mismatch errors.